# Is it possible to scale Navigation Icons for Responsive Design?

Tags: image-resizing, responsive-design, css

So I've scaled featured images using the max-width property but I'm wondering if the same effect can be achieved on nav image icons? Can this be done with image sprites or what would be the recommended method?

Comment: You COULD use SVGs, but support is still sketchy last I heard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load a different image size depending on the Media Queries break point.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (max-width : 320px) {
       #navIcon {
         background-image:url('small.jpg');
       }
    }


/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
   #navIcon {
     background-image:url('normal.jpg');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how much you want your layout to change, and if you need to match certain requirements of the vendor (apple's guidelines, for instance)

I've had a website where all the menu images were identical heights, and used a linear layout if on a wider screen.

The minute you change it to a smaller screen I included an @media specific size and placement requirement for the menu icons. For instance, I wanted them to stack and I wanted them to be 42 pixels high (what Apple says is the minimum touchable size for touch screens)

For the desktop I had a specific width and height set to 'auto', and for the narrower screen I had a specific height (42px) and the width set to 'auto'.

I tend not to want to rely on multiple images because it does make it more difficult to maintain over time. In fact, I stopped using images for my menus and have done everything using css (no monotone image sprites for me, though. I use a home made dingbat web font that scales quite nicely)

Answer (score 1):

you can do what Kris said plus use a sprite by doing background position.

You can also use  and do a height 100%.

I would recommend what Kris suggested.